# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getattribute

I'm trying to create a class in JavaScript to validate a form. That'll check the form elements and validate a field if it has a specific attribute.

However, the call to `getAttribute` isn't returning a value. It doesn't get the value inside another variable, but, if I print, it works well.

Here's the code for my class:

```
function valida() {
    document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML="";
    var totalErros=0; 
    var x=document.getElementById("frm1");
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        var input=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
        var campo=input.getAttribute("id");
        var tipo=input.getAttribute("tipo");
        var nome=input.getAttribute("nome");
        var id=campo.toString(); //the error goes here
        //var valor=_$(id).value;
        alert(campo);

        switch (tipo) {
            case "obrigatorio":
                if(document.getElementById(id).value==""){
                    document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML+="Deu erro no campo "+nome+"<br />"; 
                    totalErros++;}
                    break
            case "oemail":
                if(document.getElementById(id).value==""){
                    document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML+="Deu erro no campo "+nome+"<br />"; 
                    totalErros++;}
                    break
            case "email":
                if(!ValidaEmail(document.getElementById(id).value)){
                    document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML+="O "+nome+" que você informou é inválido "+document.getElementById(id).value+"  <br />"; 
                    totalErros++;}
                    break
            default:
                document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML+="<br />";
        }            
    }
    if(totalErros==0) {  
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML="Agora foi "+ totalErros;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your English is good enough, Toni!

Comment: Doing `var input=document.getElementsByTagName("input")` over and over again in the for loop is bad for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
var input=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
var campo=input.getAttribute("id");
//...
var id=campo.toString(); //the error goes here
```

You are getting a given input element and storing it in the variable `input`. You are then getting the ID of that element and storing it in the variable `campo`. You then take `campo` and call toString() on it.

The problem is that at least one input element does not have an ID. Because you cannot call `toString` on `null`, you get an error.

You don't actually need to call `toString()` in the first place. Simply use `campo` as is. It will either be null (if there is no ID) or a string.

Comment: thank you! How silly of me. hee hee, really some input hasn't an ID.

Comment: Glad to help :). Consider marking this as the answer if you feel it would help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code piqued my curiosity:

```
var x=document.getElementById("frm1");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    var input=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
```

This takes the collection of **all** `<input>` elements on your page and takes the `i`th one *each time*; and who knows what input element you may get.

If you just want to traverse only the elements of the form you're interested in, this is much easier and faster:

```
var x = document.getElementById('frm1'),
input,
campo;

for (var i = 0, n = x.length; i != n; ++i) {
    input = x.elements[i];
    if (campo = input.id) {
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```

As you can see, I take the `id` property instead of the `id` attribute; this is generally a better thing to do, because changes in properties may not always be reflected in the respective attribute.

Also, the `.toString()` is superfluous, it's already a string if not null.

**Update**

As @bfavaretto pointed out in the comment section, this part of your code could also be simplified:

```
if(document.getElementById(id).value==""){
```

to this:

```
if (input.value == '') {
```

*That would work whether the input element has an id or not*

Comment: Also, the calls to `document.getElementById(id)` in the `switch` statement can be replaced by `input` too.

Comment: Sounds great! I'll rewrite the code according your hints. Thank you. You guys save my job, LOL.

Comment: @ToniCesarA.Amaral Good luck; if you get it working and this answer sufficiently helped you consider to accept it by clicking the check mark :)